# Robot tilting problem on linear acceleration

Tags: friction, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to simulate someting close to the [Nexus 3-wheeled platform](http://www.nexusrobot.com/product/3wd-100mm-omni-wheel-mobile-arduino-robot-kit-10013.html).

When I accelerate with 2 wheels in the direction of the third, the latter wheel gets raised into the air. I used the fomulas on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia) to calculate my inertia. For the mass I tried with 10, 100, 200 kg with the same tilting result.

I mananged to set the friction directly in the .sdf file generated from my urdf.

```
<friction>
  <ode>
    <mu>0.9</mu>
    <mu2>0.001</mu2>
    <fdir1>0 1.0 0</fdir1>
  </ode>
</friction>
```

(I set it directly in the .sdf file because i noticed another problem described [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16343/setting-friction-params/).)

I also setup the joint model stiffness parameters **kp, kd** like so:

```
  <contact>
    <ode>
      <kp>1e+08</kp>
      <kd>1</kd>
    </ode>
  </contact>
```

in order to have some stiff wheels when in contact with the ground plane, otherwise they pass through.

Would I need to setup something else? I am using ros-kinetic and the gazebo delivered with it, Gazebo7.
(I use ros_control ( a modified version of diff_drive_controller for the 3-wheeled base) and of course continuous joints)

Tnx and regards!

**UPDATE**

I also had a small arm on top of my robot, with a really small weight compared to the base but with it's own inertia. I deleted all that and now I just have a base with 3 wheels and it works fine. For now it's ok for what I need but for the future I will need the arm also.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16532/robot-tilting-problem-on-linear-acceleration/) by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-06-27**:
It's the third wheel that raises? How high? What's the acceleration? Do you have a video of the behavior?

**Comment by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) on 2017-06-28**:
Yes the third wheel (aith the base link too, not just the wheel alone), like it had a huge inertial value on the robot. Not too high because my robot is low so it hits the ground with the back of the base_link. I made an update in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So i had this problem because of a prismatic joint I was using:

I managed to use `velocity_controllers/JointPositionController` instead of `position_controllers/JointPositionController` with the prismatic joint. You just need to add a PID for it. Here's an example.

Before:

```
arm_controller:
  type: "position_controllers/JointPositionController"
  joint: arm_joint
```

After:

```
arm_controller:
  type: "velocity_controllers/JointPositionController"
  joint: arm_joint
  pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 1.0}
```

And for the transmission:

```
<hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface </hardwareInterface>
```

Same answer/problem [here.](http://answers.ros.org/question/256743/prismatic-joint-with-positionjointinterface-interferes-with-gazebo-physics/#265920)

---

Originally posted by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) with karma: 41 on 2017-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0